# SQL Server query analyzing

Tags: sql-server, join

I'm new to SQL,and I'm still trying to understand the basic stuff so I have this database of an application which compares products prices on the internet:

- Product (p_id, p_name, p_description, category_id, category_name, manuf_id, manuf_name)
- Product_attributes (p_id, attribute_name, attribute_name)
- Sites (site_id, site_name, site_url)
- ProductPrice (p_id, site_id, from_date, to_date, price, product_site_url)

and this query :

```
SELECT 
    MAX(p1.price - p2.price)
FROM 
    ProdcutPrice p1 
JOIN
    ProdcutPrice p2 ON p1.p_id = p2.p_id AND p1.site_id <> p2.site_id 
WHERE 
    p1.p_id = 18 AND to_date IS NULL
```

Now I'm trying to understand what does this query do, I'm having a hard time understanding the `MAX` function, for all I know it should return the largest value of the selected column. And the syntax should be

```
SELECT MAX(column_name) 
FROM table_name;
```

also does the `JOIN` clause work like `INNER JOIN`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MAX(expression)` finds maximum value of expression among all found records (filtered by `WHERE`). NB: among all records if you don't specify `GROUP BY`.

`JOIN` without any additional word is `INNER JOIN` by default.

Sample:

**ProductPrice**:

```
p_id | site_id | price
-----|---------|------
18   | 1       | 10
18   | 2       | 5
18   | 3       | 7
```

**Query**:

```
p1.p_id | p1.site_id | p1.price | p2.p_id | p2.site_id | p2.price | p1.price-p2.price
--------|------------|----------|----- ---|------------|----------|------------------
18      | 1          | 10       | 18      | 2          | 5        | 5 (max)
18      | 1          | 10       | 18      | 3          | 7        | 3
18      | 2          | 5        | 18      | 1          | 10       | -5
18      | 2          | 5        | 18      | 3          | 7        | -2
18      | 3          | 7        | 18      | 1          | 10       | -3
18      | 3          | 7        | 18      | 2          | 5        | 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed `JOIN` is equivalent to `INNER JOIN`.

If you run the query without the `MAX()` aggregate function like this:

```
SELECT p1.price - p2.price
FROM ...
```

you will see that it returns a column. So it is perfectly legitimate to apply an aggregate to this column, such as `MAX` or `SUM`.